# Ubuntu 14.04.1 Disable the mounting of internal hdd (sda)

Tags: mount, fstab, automount

I am running ubuntu from a usb stick and I would like to prevent ubuntu from seeing my internal hdd, so it would be impossible to mount. How is the best way to do this? I added /dev/hda1 / auto noauto 0 0
in fstab but that did not do the job...

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Why did you add /dev/hda1 if your title suggests /dev/sda?

Comment: `/dev/sda  /media/Folder auto defaults,noauto,umask=777 0 0` will deny mounting  to normal user.

Answer (score 0):

First find out the UUID of your partition.

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i

blkid /dev/sda1
```

Second, create a mount point (/mnt/mydisk) accessible only to root:

```
sudo -i

mkdir /mnt/mydisk
```

Third  edit the file /etc/fstab, and add the lines not mount:

```
sudo -i

nano /etc/fstab


#/dev/sda1 was /mnt/mydisk
UUID=A70889A1788980GG /mnt/mydisk <file system> noauto,umask=222 0 0
```

Now after reboot from the usb-stick, you should not mount the partition, only root can mount it with the mount command.

Comment: Brilliant! I can't even see it in "Files". This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks